# Kendo UI Template refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-template

I set up a hierarchical grid with Kendo UI, and I need a way to sort by names.

I have buttons of the alphabet set up to filter names where the first letter equals the letter of the button you clicked, but it won't filter it correctly.

It loads fine, with all the data available. When I click a letter, nothing changes in the first row you expand, and the filter starts working on the rows you expand after the first one, even though the variable gets set. See image at the bottom for an illustration of the problem.

The template

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="client-report-detail-template">
    # var active, inactive; $.each(data.clients, function(key, client) { #

        #if(client.status == 20) { active = 1; } else { active = 0; } #
        #if(client.status != 20) { inactive = 1; } else { inactive = 0 } #

        #if(sortBy.length > 0 && sortBy == client.administration_name[0]) { #
            <div class="client-report-detail-container">
                <div class="client-report-detail-pane">#= client.administration_name #</p></div>
                <div class="client-report-detail-pane">#= client.is_new #</p></div>
                <div class="client-report-detail-pane">#= active #</p></div>
                <div class="client-report-detail-pane">#= inactive #</p></div>
            </div>
        # } #

        #if(sortBy.length == 0) { #
            <div class="client-report-detail-container">
                <div class="client-report-detail-pane">#= client.administration_name #</p></div>
                <div class="client-report-detail-pane">#= client.is_new #</p></div>
                <div class="client-report-detail-pane">#= active #</p></div>
                <div class="client-report-detail-pane">#= inactive #</p></div>
            </div>
        # } #
    # }); #
</script>
```

The buttons (using Laravel's Blade)

```
@foreach(range('A', 'Z') as $letter)
    <button data-type="name" data-value="{{ $letter }}" class="k-button bizme-button-round filter-text fcl">{{ $letter }}</button>
@endforeach
```

What I got so far that happens when you click on one of the buttons

```
$(".fcl").on('click tap', function() {
    sortByLetter = $(this).data().value;

    $("#client-report-grid-container").data("kendoGrid").refresh();
});
```

The grid setup and detail init

```
$("#client-report-grid-container").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        data: gridData,
        pageSize: 15
    },
    detailTemplate: kendo.template($("#client-report-detail-template").html()),
    detailInit: detailInit,
    columns: [
        {
            field: "date",
            title: "{{ trans('form.month') }}"
        },
        {
            field: "new"
        },
        {
            field: "active"
        },
        {
            field: "inactive"
        }
    ]
});

function detailInit(){
    $.each(this.dataSource.data(), function(key, data) {
        data.sortBy = sortByLetter;
    });
};
```

Anyone know how to solve this issue?

[image: Don't judge on my Paint skills :)]

Comment: Can you provide a demo in dojo.telerik.com for us ?

Comment: Working on it, will post the link when I got the demo done.

Comment: [demo link](http://dojo.telerik.com/EyIkU).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens is that the [`detailTemplate`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-detailTemplate) runs before [`detailInit`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-detailInit), the detail is rendered before the event. So in the template the `sortBy` is not set yet. Then the event runs and sets it. That is why it works in the second time. To check that, add a `console.log("detailInit")` in the first row inside the `detailInit` event and a `# console.log("template"); #` inside the template and check the console.

My suggestion to fix that is to set the sort values inside the grid's [`dataBound`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-dataBound) event instead of the `detailInit` event:

```
dataBound: function()
{
    $.each(this.dataSource.data(), function(key, data) {
        data.sortBy = sortByLetter;
    });
}
```

Just like that. `dataBound` is called anytime grid's [`refresh()`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-refresh) method runs, so the `sortBy` values are set before the detail is rendered, thus the template can read the right `sortBy` values.

[Working demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/EyIkU/4).

Comment: @Kibo great! nice to help. Kendo has this lacks of events, most of its events run after some action so you have pay attention on *when*  they run.